# Jmeter Hitting multiple hits on single url with 1 thread and 1 loop count

Tags: jmeter

`I have 4 urls`
    ``` ``https://vinfax-api.designitic.com/ ```
    ``` ``https://vinfax-api.designitic.com/login ```
    ``` ``https://vinfax-api.designitic.com/user/subscription ```
    ``` ``https://vinfax-api.designitic.com/user/download-history ```

`in jemeter i have select 1 thread and 1 loop count but when I run the script the jmeter hits multiple times on same URL.`

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjQdj.png) 
    [`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bceWk.png)

`i want to run the same script only 4 times rather than multiple time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 possible causes:

1. [Redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) (i.e. from HTTP to HTTPS or your system under test internal redirects)
2. [Embedded Resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) (JMeter downloads images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.)

In your case it's caused by "embedded resources" so your expectation is kind of incorrect, you should not "want to run the same script only 4 times" you should make sure that JMeter generates the same network footprint as the real browser.

[image]

If you still "want" to disable downloading of embedded resources untick the corresponding box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

[image]